# Creating a new config parameter in wdio.config.js in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ui-automation, angular-fullstack, webdriver-io-v4

I am writing an automation framework and wondering how to create environment properties file like Java.

I know wdio.config.js is the place where we hold baseURL and other stuff. 
Say I would like to create new placeholders like "Login" which accepts string or "username" which is a string as well. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `Login: "loginuser"` or `password: "password"` in `wdio.config.js` worked.
These are accessible using `browser.config.loginuser` or `browser.config.password`